# for loop in oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, increment

I want the value i to increment by 1 for every insert in the table employee_dep

```
i := 1
For lh in
 (SELECT DISTINCT z.emp_id
           FROM employee z)
LOOP
 INSERT INTO employee_dep
        (emp_id, emp_lfd, dep_name, dept_no)
        SELECT w.emp_id, i, w.dep_name, w.dep_no)
        FROM
          central_dep w
        where w.emp_id= lh.emp_id;
         i := i+1;
end loop;
```

But if there are two rows with same emp_id then i is same for both the rows.
I want i to be incremented by 1 in the next row. (i to be incremented by 1 for every new insert in the table)

for eg.
i wanted the columns to be

```
emp_id emp_lfd
1111     1
1111     2
1111     3
1122     1
1122     2
1122     3
1122     4
```

But what i am currently getting is

```
emp_id emp_lfd
1111     3
1111     3
1111     3
1122     4
1122     4    
1122     4
1122     4
```

Comment: Use a `generated always as identity` column.  Much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you just need `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function with `PARTITION BY emp_id` within your `INSERT` statement such as

```
INSERT INTO employee_dep(emp_id, emp_lfd, dep_name, dept_no)
SELECT emp_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY 0), dep_name, dep_no
  FROM central_dep
```

I've tried to regenerate your case within the <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84c1f871440228037bb90206ff92cd71)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want an `insert ... select` statement with `row_number()`?

```
insert into employee_dep (emp_id, emp_lfd, dep_name, dept_no)
select emp_id, row_number() over(order by emp_id), dep_name, dep_no
from central_dep
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are practicing PL/SQL, that would be a nested loop, e.g.

```
DECLARE
   i  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   i := 1;

   FOR lh IN (SELECT DISTINCT z.emp_id
                FROM employee z)
   LOOP
      FOR cur_r IN (SELECT w.emp_id, w.dep_name, w.dep_no
                      FROM central_dep w
                     WHERE w.emp_id = lh.emp_id)
      LOOP
         INSERT INTO employee_dep (emp_id,
                                   emp_lfd,
                                   dep_name,
                                   dept_no)
              VALUES (cur_r.emp_id,
                      i,
                      cur_r.dep_name,
                      cur_r.dep_no);

         i := i + 1;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```